# Was there a professional sports competition where every entrant was a previous winner?

Tags: trivia, history

Has there ever been a professional sports division that was, at any time, solely comprised of former league champions?

Answer (score 3):

**NHL**

1. **1998-2013 Atlantic**
   a. Philadelphia Flyers (First win 1974)
   b. New York Rangers (1928)
   c. New York Islanders (1980)
   d. New Jersey Devils (1995)
   e. Pittsburgh Penguins (1991)
2. **1967-1970 East**
   a. Montreal Canadiens (1916)
   b. Boston Bruins (1929)
   c. New York Rangers (1928)
   d. Detroit Red Wings (1936)
   e. Chicago Black Hawks (1934)
   f. Toronto Maple Leafs (1918)
3. **1941-1967 Unnamed, only conference**
   a. Montreal Canadiens (1916)
   b. Boston Bruins (1929)
   c. New York Rangers (1928)
   d. Detroit Red Wings (1936)
   e. Chicago Black Hawks (1934)
   f. Toronto Maple Leafs (1918)
4. **1936-1938 American**
   a. Boston Bruins (1929)
   b. Chicago Black Hawks (1934)
   c. Detroit Red Wings (1936)
   d. New York Rangers (1928)

---

**NFL, Super Bowls only**

1. **2018-Present NFC East**
   a. Philadelphia Eagles (2017)
   b. Dallas Cowboys (1971)
   c. Washington Redskins (1982)
   d. New York Giants (1986)

---

**Pre-Merger NFL**

1. **1945-1949 Western**
   a. Chicago Bears (1921)
   b. Chicago Cardinals (1925)
   c. Detroit Lions (1935)
   d. Green Bay Packers (1929)
   e. Los Angeles Rams (1945)
2. **1943 Western**
   a. Chicago Bears (1921)
   b. Chicago Cardinals (1925)
   c. Detroit Lions (1935)
   d. Green Bay Packers (1929)
3. **1935-36 Western**
   a. Chicago Bears (1921)
   b. Chicago Cardinals (1925)
   c. Detroit Lions (1935)
   d. Green Bay Packers (1929)

---

**Never happened in the pre-merger AFL**

---

**MLB**

1. **1994-1997 AL East**
   a. Baltimore Orioles (1966)
   b. Boston Red Sox (1903)
   c. New York Yankees (1923)
   d. Detroit Tigers (1935)
   e. Toronto Blue Jays (1992)
2. **1998-Current AL Central**
   a. Chicago White Sox (1906)
   b. Cleveland Indians (1920)
   c. Kansas City Royals (1985)
   d. Minnesota Twins (1924 *As Washington Nationals, 1987 as Twins)
   e. Detroit Tigers (1935)

Neither the National League or the American League was comprised of solely previous champions before realignment in the 1960s.

---

**Has never happened in the NBA or the ABA**

---

I'll stop there since I've covered the "Big 4" of American Professional sports. Source was me going through Wikipedia comparing division timelines with lists of champions, seeing if there was a team that hadn't won yet in any given division.

Answer (score 0):

The easy one here is the NHL during the [Original Six era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_Six). All six teams played in one division, and all won a championship before the 1967 expansion; while the Rangers never won a championship during the Original Six era, they won three championships before 1942.

Other than that, every time in the [NFC West](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFC_West) has won at least one championship:

- The 49ers have won five Superbowls, most recently [Super Bowl XXIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_XXIX).
- The Cardinals won the [1947 NFL season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1947_NFL_season).
- The Rams franchise won [Super Bowl XXXIV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_XXXIV) while based in St Louis.
- The Seahawks won [Super Bowl XLVII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_XXXIV).

If it happens that the Eagles win [Super Bowl LII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_LII), then every team in the NFC East will also have won a championship.